# Meaning of the percentage property of background of body in CSS?

Tags: background, percentage

What is the meaning of that 50% of an image, I have changed it several times to 20 o 100 percent and it doesnt seem to do anything

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It moves the image 50%(half-way) to the right on the x-axis inside the browser window. Try background:url(../images/mockups01.png) no-repeat 50% 0 fixed; and play around with the percentage to see if it makes a difference. In addition, you can also change the 0 to let's say 10% and it will move the image 10% down.